# Laravel Jetstream получить id пользователя

Tags: laravel

Установил Laravel Jetstream и пытаюсь понять как в контроллере получить Id текущего пользователя ?

Comment: `Auth::id()` или `Auth::user()->id`

Answer (score 1):

Тестировал на Laravel 8.

**1. Auth::**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::id();
```

**2. Request**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{
     $request->user()->id;
}
```

**3. auth функция**

```
auth()->id();
```